gulp-notify: [HTML] Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
gulp-notify: [HTML] Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
Только недавно начал gulp изучать, писал код по уроку, перезапустил vs code и тут эта ошибка вылезла (до этого только создал файл .json для массива, чтобы быстрее создавать карточки с отзывами + добавил в html @@loop('./templates/card-review.html' './data/testimonials.json')). Переменной match нигде нет, все файлы проверил. Переустанавливал отдельно gulp-noyify, gulp и node_modules + packaje-lock.json. По этой причине сайт не отображается, а пишет "Cannot GET /". В консоли тоже ниче не отображается
[23:01:30] gulp-notify: [HTML] Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

Похоже на ошибку javaScript сайта
